# Many teachers from different institutions moodle 2.8

Tags: module, moodle

Suppose there are many institutions under which there are n number of teachers who will be given a course to handle, under whom there will be n number of students. Each institution have a head teacher who can monitor all the students in their institution and see the over all performance of the students. Each teacher in should get the report of their respective students. Admin should be able to handle all the institutions.

Is this feasible? if yes,  how can this be implemented. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is effectively multi-client functionality.  Moodle does not, by default, offer this kind of support.  It is *possible* that you can do this at the student level using carefully constructed cohort membership with categories available to the relevant people.  You can even force custom themes at the category/course/user level to give a different appearance.  However, my guess is that you will run into issues when you start thinking about how to implement the elevated permissions for headteachers but restrict them to a given institution only.

There may also be issues of data protection (particularly where schools are concerned) which, depending on your customers' locations and the legislation in force in those countries/areas, you may need to ensure you comply with.  Additionally, if all of the data is within the same database, how would you deal with one institution requiring a roll-back while others have no need?

TL;DR: My view would be that Moodle is so cheap to install, host and support that you may as well install separate sites for each institution.